# how to ignore unclicked div elements in the screenshot html2canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html2canvas

so basically I'm working on my personal pixel art project.  The whole pixel drawing art is a row of divs like so:

```
<div id="art">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="pixel" onmousedown="setPixelColour(this)"></div>
            <div class="pixel" onmousedown="setPixelColour(this)"></div>
            <div class="pixel" onmousedown="setPixelColour(this)"></div>
            <div class="pixel" onmousedown="setPixelColour(this)"></div>
            <div class="pixel" onmousedown="setPixelColour(this)"></div>
            <div class="pixel" onmousedown="setPixelColour(this)"></div>
            <div class="pixel" onmousedown="setPixelColour(this)"></div>
            <div class="pixel" onmousedown="setPixelColour(this)"></div>
            <div class="pixels" onmousedown="setPixelColour(this)"></div>
            <div class="pixels" onmousedown="setPixelColour(this)"></div>
            <div class="pixels" onmousedown="setPixelColour(this)"></div>
            <div class="pixels" onmousedown="setPixelColour(this)"></div>
            <div class="pixels" onmousedown="setPixelColour(this)"></div>
            <div class="pixels" onmousedown="setPixelColour(this)"></div>
            <div class="pixels" onmousedown="setPixelColour(this)"></div>
            <div class="pixels" onmousedown="setPixelColour(this)"></div>


        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="pixel" onmousedown="setPixelColour(this)"></div>
            <div class="pixel" onmousedown="setPixelColour(this)"></div>
            <div class="pixel" onmousedown="setPixelColour(this)"></div>
            <div class="pixel" onmousedown="setPixelColour(this)"></div>
            <div class="pixel" onmousedown="setPixelColour(this)"></div>
            <div class="pixel" onmousedown="setPixelColour(this)"></div>
            <div class="pixel" onmousedown="setPixelColour(this)"></div>
            <div class="pixel" onmousedown="setPixelColour(this)"></div>
            <div class="pixels" onmousedown="setPixelColour(this)"></div>
            <div class="pixels" onmousedown="setPixelColour(this)"></div>
            <div class="pixels" onmousedown="setPixelColour(this)"></div>
            <div class="pixels" onmousedown="setPixelColour(this)"></div>
            <div class="pixels" onmousedown="setPixelColour(this)"></div>
            <div class="pixels" onmousedown="setPixelColour(this)"></div>
            <div class="pixels" onmousedown="setPixelColour(this)"></div>
            <div class="pixels" onmousedown="setPixelColour(this)"></div>

        </div>
```

Basically after the user is done creating his pixel art, they get an option to save the masterpiece, and this is where i implemented html2canvas.

```
<script src="html2canvas.js"></script>
    <script>function doCapture(){
        html2canvas(document.getElementById("art")).then(function(canvas){

            console.log(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.9));
            alert("Go to Developer Console in dev tools, Copy and Paste the base64 value of image in the URL to see it in JPEG format")})}</script>
<button onmousedown="doCapture();">Save Masterpiece?</button>
```

This is what it looks like so far:

[image: Rendered White space in screenshot]

As you can see, the untouched white space part of the canvas also gets in the screen shot, is there a way  where I can prevent untouched div elements to end up in the screenshot in html2canvas?

To clarify, after the user has finished their pixel art, the saved image will get stored in a database and the user will be able to place their image wherever the mouse is clicked.  This is why I want transparency in the images.

Comment: its not simple to automate, you could remove the element before save but it might affect the result, you could also detect x axis cols whitespace from the dom and remove them cols which would not work if first block is colored and rest not, you could also trim the final image with canvas getImageData, all tricky.. the simplest solution would be to allow the user to change the grid size themself which would then allow for any size canvas, or implement a crop select before save or after both easier then auto cropping it.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone But all of those options would not work on all submissions.  I tried creating an if statement that added the built in html2canvas attribute which hides the element if the element was not clicked.  This also did not work.

Comment: yep, it looks simple to just remove the whitespace, but computers are stupid, why would a custom size grid, or a drag select and save not work? Any solution is going to be more then a few if statements

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Because with a custom grid, there could be still some untouched areas left,  what I'm trying to do is add just the edited elements into the screenshot.  Making it transparent.  Sorry, I should've clarified, but basically once the user is done, he will place his image on the drawing board which is on my website.  This is why I am trying to make them transparent.